# How to get content of loaded stylesheet

Tags: javascript, css, ajax, stylesheet

I'd like to get the stylesheet rules (or css textContent) from css files linked in the head of my page. `document.styleSheets` seems to work in all major browsers, but `styleSheets[0].cssRules` of course fails in IE<9 . What is the proper approach for this solution ? Loading files with AJAX ? But then I'm just limited to styles from the same domain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For IE you can use `rules` property of `styleSheets` objects.

So the universal solution can be:

```
var list = null;
with (document.styleSheets[0]) {
    if (typeof cssRules != "undefined")
        list = cssRules;
    else if (typeof rules != "undefined")
        list = rules;
}
console.log(list);​
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/tqgNb/

Comment: pitty that of course they block stylesheets from different domain :/