# Can I get text source of link stylesheet?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I try to get css as text from link element.
For example for `style` element it is simplest:

```
[].map.call(document.styleSheets, function(styleSheet) {
  var tag = styleSheet.ownerNode.tagName.toLowerCase();
  if (tag == 'style') {
    return styleSheet.ownerNode.textContent;
  } else if (tag == 'link') {
    //is it possible to receive source here without ajax?
  }
});
```

Is there any way to get link source without loading it as text?

Answer (score 1):

With `document.styleSheets` you can interate through all loaded stylesheets on the page. Each one is a list of css rules elements. You can obtain the `cssText` property of these css rules.

Based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10831703/how-to-get-content-of-loaded-stylesheet), I've come up with a sample script to get all css rules text loaded on the page. Hope it helps...

http://jsfiddle.net/qMAW7/1/

```
var cssStyles = "";

//Started at index 1 for index 0 is browser's user agent stylesheet.
for(var i=1; i<document.styleSheets.length; i++) {
    var style = null;
    with (document.styleSheets[i]) {
        if (typeof cssRules != "undefined")
            style = cssRules;
        else if (typeof rules != "undefined")
            style = rules;
    }
    for(var item in style) {
        if(style[item].cssText != undefined)
            cssStyles = (style[item].cssText);
    }
}

alert(cssStyles);
```

Comment: This is true only for valid css rules. For example, if in source exist '-moz-box-sizing' and css has loaded in chrome, this option will deleted

Comment: i think you need to make it `cssStyles += "\n"+ (style[item].cssText);`