# Get the contents of an included css file with Javascript and/or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm making a docs site where I display html, css and js examples. Currently I grab the html of the navbar and put it into a code block:

```
$(".navbars #navbar .html code").text($(".navbar")[0].outerHTML);
```

I want to be able to do something similar with the css. All the navbar css is included like so:

```
<link href="css/navbar.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

First I thought to grab it with an ajax request, but since I'm not running a server (just a simple html, css and js website), I get a `Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.` error.

Second I thought maybe there's a way to use jQuery to grab all the css of an element and its children. I had no luck with this idea.

The optimal solution would be to use the file (that's already being included on the page) and grab the contents, but I haven't been able to find out how to interact with a css file that's included already. Any help/ideas would be appreciated!

Comment: have you tried to do this: $("link[rel='stylesheet']").each(function (){ var url = 'your-server-or-file-location'+$(this).attr('href'); $.ajax({url:url, data:{},method:'post'}).done(function(sourceCode){console.log(sourceCode); }}); I think you problem is that send the ajax to css/navbar.css instead of the whole url (even if not a server)

Comment: Check [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10831703/how-to-get-content-of-loaded-stylesheet).

Comment: @Harry That looks like exactly what I'm looking for! I'll let you know if it works

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to make a simple $.get request to ANY valid local path.  Perhaps you'll need to fiddle with the request content type.

Try including jQuery & using

```
$.get{"css/navbar.css",function(data){
   $(".navbars #navbar .html code").text(data);
});
```

Comment: This is what I meant by using an ajax request. I got the error in the question